# Read/Write multimedia/office files

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to have access to image/video/audio/office files in wp7 from my silverlight application. I want to be able to read and write files. Is this functionallity locked or avaliable to developers? how about mango release? Any idea? :))

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add and read images, music and video files to and from the [MediaLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary_members.aspx) on the phone but not office files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can read and write (audio/video..) files in WP7 from your Silverlight application running on WP7. However, you can only access files belonging to your application. WP7 / Silverlight applications can read/read files from your application package (XAP) or isolated storage, essentially a sandbox restricted to your application.  Take a look at this [introduction to Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

This is available in 7.0 as well as in Mango.

Comment: I'm aware of isolated storage. What I want to know is if I can write multimedia content in the phone, so it will be accessible by the phone itself :)